# How to duplicate values according to record count from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table that contains dates, the table can have multiple dates in it. For Example

```
Date
'2011-01-01'
'2011-03-01'
'2011-06-01'
'2011-11-01'
'2011-12-01'
```

I also have a table that just has units in it. There will never be duplicate units.

```
Unit
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How do I return all dates for every unit. For example:

```
Unit           Date
1           '2011-01-01'
1           '2011-03-01'
1            '2011-06-01'
1            '2011-11-01'
1            '2011-12-01'
2           '2011-01-01'
2           '2011-03-01'
2            '2011-06-01'
2            '2011-11-01'
2            '2011-12-01'
```

and so on.....

Comment: you say the first table can have _multiple_ dates, but can it have _duplicate_ dates?

Comment: The result you desire is called a cartesian product.

Comment: No it can't hgave duplicate dates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `CROSS JOIN`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx

```
SELECT d.[Date]
       ,u.[Unit]
FROM [Date_Table] d
CROSS JOIN [Unit_Table] u
```

Query assumes `Date` column is in `Date_Table`, and `Unit` column is in `Unit_Table`